# Check if statement, not case sensitive

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a fake run box to use against Technical Support Scammers to waste their time. I want to have some specified text run a msgbox. Is there a way to accept all cases? (notepad, NoTePaD, NOTEPAD etc.).

```
If textbox1.text = "Notepad" Then
Msgbox("Unable to open")
```

Comment: Please hover your mouse over the tags, read the words and decide which *one* actually applies and remove the other two

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit confused as to what "all versions of it" means, however the following will ignore spaces and capitalization:

```
Dim str As String = textbox1.text.ToLower().Replace(" ", "")
If str = "notepad" Then MsgBox("Unable to open")
```

This is a VB.Net solution, however as [Plutonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070452/plutonix) mentioned in the comments, it's hard to tell what sort of solution you're looking for - you've tagged two different types of VB.